# Errors running ng lint on newly created Angular workspace

Tags: node.js, angular-cli, eslint, nomachine-nx

I have created a new Angular workspace using the following sequence of commands:

```
npx ng new starwars --prefix ts --routing --style scss
cd starwars
npx ng add @ngrx/store@latest # accepting the defaults
npx ng lint # accepting the installation and the defaults
```

Then, running `ng lint`, "All files pass listing.", but I then receive this error:

> /Users/someuser/Desktop/toyota-starwars/node_modules/@nrwl/devkit/src/utils/convert-nx-executor.js:54
> .next()
> ^
>
> TypeError: iterator.next is not a function

Firstly, what on earth is Nx doing in there? And what is causing this error?

I am using node 16.16.0.

---

The exactly same behaviour happens when

1. setting up an Angular application in verison 14.1.3
2. and adding eslint by using "ng add @angular-eslint/schematics"
   "@nrwl/devkit" is in version "14.5.8"

Comment: I just bumped into this same issue after installing `@angular-eslint/builder@14.0.2`. I had to go back to v14.0.0. `@nrwl/devkit` seems to be the problematic dependency there, too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in `@nrwl/devkit` package that the `@angular-eslint/builder` depends on. It has been reported in their GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/11653). A fix has just been merged to master and will probably be included in the next (14.5.9?) release.

Edit: fix has been published with @angular-eslint/builder v14.0.3 (see comment)

Comment: npm i @angular-eslint/builder@14.0.3 @angular-eslint/eslint-plugin@14.0.3 - This fixed by project

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I shall try that.